# Spotipy search track name and return album, track and artist

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm trying to get to grips with spotipy (again) I'm trying to return the artist, album, and track name from  search by track title.

```py
track = "Pretend we're dead"
results = sp.search(q="track:" + track, type="track")

for idx, artist, album, track in enumerate(results['tracks']['artist']['album']['items']):
    print(idx, track['name'], track['artist'], album['album'])
```

Expected results:

1. Pretend We're Dead, L7, Bricks Are Heavy
2. Pretend We're Dead, L7, Pretend We're Dead - The Best Of
3. Pretend We're Dead - Remastered, L7, Fast & Frightning

I'm failing on deconstructing the list comprehension that are the results.

The error I'm getting is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(idx, track['name'], track['artist_id'])
KeyError: 'artist_id'
```

Comment: Sorry - Added error message - which relates to the print statement.

Comment: What keys does `track` have?

Comment: Also, can you check your code?  Nowhere do you reference `track['artist_id']`.

Comment: I know - it's a stab in the dark. I've not found enough examples to give me a good idea of how to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-track), I see that the response is going to look like this (leaving out the boring parts):

```json
{
  "album": {}
  "artists": [
    {
      "genres": [
        "Prog rock",
        "Grunge"
      ],
      "href": "string",
      "id": "string",
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02ff9ca10b55ce82ae553c8228\n",
          "height": 300,
          "width": 300
        }
      ],
      "name": "string",
      "popularity": 0,
      "type": "artist",
      "uri": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Looking at this, `artists` is a key within the result, and it is a list of dictionaries, with each dict being a single artist for the track.

Using that info, this would be the way to refer to the first artist's id:

`track["artists"][0]["id"]`

If this isn't right, the trick to doing this is to just `print(json.dumps(track, indent=3))` and look at the actual JSON you are receiving.

Comment: many people make the mistake of just trying to grab a single item from a dictionary ( JSON) but this won't work if the data is nested. As @Cargo23 has explained try sorting through the data and see what happens

Comment: @cargo23 print(track["artists"][0]["id"]) comes up with 
TypeError: string indices must be integers. I know it needs a colon instead of a comma. But where?

Comment: You need to print out your JSON and see how it is really coming to you